# Copying part of array to a second array in C

Tags: c, arrays, image, matlab, image-processing

I'm writing an image processing code to perform a median filter with a variable sized window.
The greyscale image has been read into an array image1, and I'm trying to copy a window selection of the array into a second array window. This is easy for a fixed sized window (3x3 window shown) as you can just say:

```
window[1]=image1[m-((win_size-1)/2)][n-((win_size-1)/2)];
window[2]=image1[m][n-((win_size-1)/2)];
window[3]=image1[m+((win_size-1)/2)][n-((win_size-1)/2)];
window[4]=image1[m-((win_size-1)/2)][n];
window[5]=image1[m][n];
window[6]=image1[m+((win_size-1)/2)][n];
window[7]=image1[m-((win_size-1)/2)][n+((win_size-1)/2)];
window[8]=image1[m][n+((win_size-1)/2)];
window[9]=image1[m+((win_size=1)/2)][n+((win_size-1)/2)];
```

In MATLAB you can generalise this to any sized window easily by using a vector in the array call:

```
window = image1(m-((win_size-1)/2):m+((win_size-1)/2),n-((win_size-1)/2):n+((win_size-1)/2));
```

I can't work out a way to do this in C, can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: For copying large amounts of data between structures and arrays, get to know `memmove()`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Why not `memcpy`? The source and destination are not overlapping here, so no need to use intermediate storage...

Comment: Safer to recommend to newbies, and most good `memmove()` implementations do not use intermediate storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using nested for loops with a pre-defined int outside the loop. Assigned to 0 at start of first loop then +1 on each iteration.

Answer (score -2):

You will have to dynamically allocate memory for an image, whatever image may be, for an array then add it to your array. I don't know exactly how to do it in C, but in C++ it would look something like:

```
image = new Image [5];
```

Comment: It is hardly an answer.